# Explicitly terminating a stream in RxJava

Tags: rx-java

Reading up on RxJava, I noticed that you can control when a stream completes, that is, when the last emission is sent downstream. It isn't clear how you actually control this. Most of the examples I've seen on RxJava will let you create an Observable using something like "just" or "fromIterable" and an array. Each item in the array would then be sent down the stream and then the onComplete is called after the last emission is processed. Of course, you can apply operators such as "take" that will also cause onComplete to execute after the number of emissions have been sent.

But is it possible to cause onComplete to execute by some more generic operator such as "finish" (that doesn't exist)? Or do you have to rely upon the existing operators to cause the onComplete to be executed? In other words, instead of relying on some condition to be met for onComplete to get executed, can I explicitly call something to end stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TakeWhile](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takewhile.html) operator:

> mirror items emitted by an Observable until a specified condition becomes false